# Новая причина закрытия («Д/з»)

Tags: обсуждение

Теперь по нажатии *закрыть* –> *не по теме, потому что…* доступна новая причина:

> Мы не выполняем задания (в особенности домашние), но можем проверить **уже выполненные** *вами*. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив свой вариант ответа. Подробнее о том, как задавать вопросы, читайте в [Справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
>   [image: ж]

Надеемся, это упростит процесс модерации вопросов и избавит от необходимости в комментариях-клише.

Будем рады любым замечаниям и предложениям!

Comment: Здравствуйте. Заметил три небольшие ошибки в разделе "Что означает статус вопроса «закрыт» или «требует правки»?" Где можно их указать?

Comment: @Александр здравствуйте! Создайте вопрос на Мете: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. Опишите наблюдения там, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

В Справке есть понятие *сообщество*: «Мета позволяет сообществу обсуждать...».

Размытое «*Мы* не выполняем задания (в особенности домашние), но можем проверить уже выполненные вами» предлагаю заменить на более строгое:

«*Сообщество* не выполняет задания (в особенности домашние), но проверит уже выполненные вами».

Comment: Не нужно строгости, особенно такой -- "сообщество". Это и не строгость, а выспренность. Если уж убирать "мы", то, например, так: "Здесь не выполняют задания..."

Comment: Сообщество — не придумка, не особенность, не выспренность. Таким, если хотите, штатным словом в Справке названы все участники обсуждения на сайте. Впрочем, безличное «здесь не выполняют» тоже вполне уместно.